Fantasy book, red haired female protagonist, royal family, warrior
I found this book back when I was in 9th grade (2017) in my school library but I'm sure the book is older than that. It probably belonged to a series. Don't remember the name of the book nor the author. Here are a few things that I recall:

Female protagonist, red haired, curly hair, belongs to a royal family I guess.

Her family is attacked by some other group (can't remember) on the day of some grand celebration.

She finds solace in the forest nearby, meets a dark haired guy there whom she becomes friends with.

She is sort of like a warrior, smart, can fight, pretty brave too.

The name of the girl probably starts with C like Claire maybe.



You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Bronwyn's Bane fits many of the above parameters, but not all, I think. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/463123.Bronwyn_s_Bane
